# Python: slow plotting related to changed plotting defaults?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a high number of data points with matplotlib in Python 3.6, several hundred thousand to several million. I've done that before and now re-used the same script. It's mainly to check if the data looks alright, which is why I kept most things in default setting, nothing special. The code is therefore absolutely basic and doesn't look much different than

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
ax.plot(a_x, a_y,"g.",markersize=0.1)
ax.plot(b_x,b_y,"b.",markersize=0.1)
fig.savefig('out.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
```

However, it took ages when I tried it again, it wasn't done after a whole day,  while it should just run for a couple of seconds. When I tried it with just 1000 data points I discovered what the problem might be, because my output looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke50o.png), so too many labels and weird grey background that I never used before. I can solve the problem by adding lines that control the label increment, then the plotting speed is back to normal.

But I still wonder what went wrong, especially because I don't want to design the label increment every time. The labels are also problematic if I use the plotting function for variables in Spyder, which I why I assume the defaults have been changed somehow. I don't even know how this could've happened, I haven't done much in Python since everything worked just fine. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?